# Spotify embed <iframe> toggle play and pause button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, spotify

I can't seem to toggle the play button of spotify's iframe programmatically through javascript.

I am currently following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71979852/how-to-play-and-pause-spotify-embed-with-javascript) here but no luck. Though I am very new to javascript and I was only trying to recreate the code provided in the answer/comment section.

I would like to be able to toggle the play button of a track or playlist.

Here are the iframe embed code:
Example Playlist:

```
<iframe style="border-radius:12px" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX3YSRoSdA634?utm_source=generator" width="100%" height="380" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
```

Example Track:

```
<iframe style="border-radius:12px" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/4AFwnrH5atiJoAd5xS5QtR?utm_source=generator" width="100%" height="380" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
```